# Data Persistence Android

Tags: android, sqlite, file, persistence, android-sharedpreferences

I'm developing a social photo app that is like instagram and I need to improve the application performance, to do that I need to persist some data, like timeline feed, photos, messages, etc. 
I'm already using Shared Preferences to save user informations.

I don't know which is the best way to persist the data, I'm between SQLite or Files, to save the json data or something else.

Which is faster and gives me less trouble?

If somebody could help me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need different queries on this data, than i strongly recommend to use SQLite. Cause it's not possible to make select queries on files without storing it to memory.

Even if you use this object as is without any special queries, you can store json objects to base.

SQL:

1) Fast.

2) Possibility to make select queries with different WHERE condition.

3) Easy update.

4) etc

I do not see the advantages to store this data to files...

If you will store data in files, it will slow if there will be a lot of data. Even if you will use sax parser.

But, images you should store as files, and only update link on it in data base.

Comment: Yes, I thought it too. Nowadays I'm using Picasso lib to load the images, the cache is  automatic, but when I kill the app the images are gone and if I get no network, I can't see any images.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this caching images will provide better solution.
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: I'm using Picasso lib to load the images and caching them, but when I kill the app, all images are gone and it's need to reload them. I need something like instagram, they keep the nine last posts when I'm without internet and the images still there, it isn't need to load them again.

Comment: ok. You can use SQLite to hold latest images as blobs files but you need to update database when the imagelist changes so this cause inefficiency for your app b

Comment: Oh I see, I will try something like that. Thanks